# What actually happens when React component returns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render

I have noticed a difference between the data before returning and after a return of a component.

[image: before render] [image: after render]

```js
class AComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const body = <BComponent crmStatus={...}/>
    debugger // log body on the right
    // ... render as static html to electron window
    return false
  }
}

class BComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const resultRender = <article className='large'>...</article>
    debugger // log resultRender on the left
    return resultRender
  }
}
```

My former question was going to be "[How to read rendered component's className?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rymaa.png)", but I have split the questions as answering **what is actually happening and why is it like that** really started to bug me and might even give me hints to solve my problem.

#### So the question is:

What is actually happening to the component and why is it like that? I can have really complicated logic in my `render()` function, but I guess working with the components isn't that easy.

```
const headerContact = isContactInCRM ? <p>..</p> : <div>..</div>
const headerCallBtnsOrInfo = isSipEnabled && <div>..buttons..</div>
const callTimer = callDuration && <span>{callDuration}</span>
const footerNotes = <footer>..</footer>
const someImportedComponent = <MyComponent />

const resultRender = <section>
  {headerContact}
  {headerCallBtnsOrInfo}
  {callTimer}
  {footerNotes}
  {someImportedComponent}
</section>

// there is a difference in data between headerContact and someImportedComponent
// when traversing the resultRender's tree in console
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that question is still relevant, but i see one major issue in provided data: 
 - right screenshot is dump of `BComponent` component stub
 - left screenshot is dump of `article` component stub ... that's why they have different type (notice class vs string `article`)

You've probably wanted to dump 'this' in second case ...

Comment: After the component is returned, it will form a VDOM(react will add ids and etc) and append to html. But, It's still unclear what problem you are tring to solve!

Comment: @ZbigniewZagórski thank you for the insight. The question was quite old and I didn't even read it again before opening a bounty on it. What you write is exactly what I had on mind back then, but didn't understand it. Pitty that I can't award bounty to commenters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before answering the question, it's worth to look at what is JSX. It just provides syntactic sugar for the `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` function.

```
<div>
  <MyComponent/>
</div>
```

As an example, above JSX snippet will be transformed to following JavaScript code in the compilation process.

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement(MyComponent, null)
);
```

You can try out this using [Babel online repl tool](https://babeljs.io/repl). So if we rewrite your example code using normal JavaScript (after compiling JSX), it will be something like this.

```
class AComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const body = React.createElement(BComponent, { crmStatus: '...' });
    debugger // log body on the right
    // ... render as static html to electron window
    return false
  }
}

class BComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const resultRender = React.createElement('article',{ className: 'large' }, '...' );
    debugger // log resultRender on the left
    return resultRender
  }
}
```

By looking at above code, we can understand that `<BComponent crmStatus={...}/>` doesn't create a new object of `BComponent` class or call `render` method of `BComponent`. It just create a ReactElement with `BComponent` type and `crmStatus` prop. So what is a ReactElement? ReactElement is a pain JavaScript object with some properties. I recommend you to read [this post from official React blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) to get an in-depth understanding of React components, elements, and instances.

> **An element is a plain object describing a component instance or DOM node and its desired properties.** It contains only information about
>   the component type (for example, a Button), its properties (for
>   example, its color), and any child elements inside it.

Basically, what you have printed in the console is two React elements in different types. The left one is describing DOM node with type `'article'` and the right one is describing `BComponent` type React component instance. So simply you can't expect them to be the same.

Then where does React create an instance of `BComponent`? Actually, this happens internally in the React code. Usually, we don't have access to these instances or what return by their render methods in our application code.

However, React still provide an escape hatch called ['refs'](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) which you can explicitly access instances of child components. You might be able to use that approach to solve your original problem.

Hope this helps!